# Monotouch Dialog changing Section or EntryElement color using Json

Tags: json, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I need to change the background color (or any color at all) of an entire section using Monotouch dialog.
Some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312150/how-to-set-the-background-color-on-a-dialogviewcontroller-monotouch-dialog) propose to subclass the DialogViewController but using Json to load the UI doesn't give that option (Or maybe it does but i dont get how do to it).

Same thing using EntryElement, the "background", "textcolor", "detailcolor" and "color" properties work for the StringElement but not for the EntryElement.
I've tried with the GetCell() method but without good results.

Any leads on this are greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Maybe copying the entire JsonElement tree, and subclassing it to something under my control ...

Comment: Directly editing the DialogViewController is also possible, but haven't figured out how to edit the color of a cell yet