# Setting background color for real in Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

Ok, I'm doing this:

```
    UIButton btReturn;

    btReturn = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);

    btReturn.Frame = btnBounds;
    btReturn.SetTitle (Caption, UIControlState.Normal);

    btReturn.Layer.CornerRadius = 14;
    btReturn.ClipsToBounds = true;
    btReturn.TouchUpInside += touchHandler;
    btReturn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB (0xe4, 0x96, 0x37);
    return btReturn;
```

Which begs the question... Why the heck is it come up as WHITE background???  I originally tried to set it to clear with a background image, but that doesn't work either...

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `RoundedRect` type of `UIButton` doesn't allow for any other colour background apart from white.

You'll have to use a `UIButtonType.Custom` to change the background colour (but you'll lose the nice rounded button and end up with a square button - you'll have to design your own fancy looking button in your favourite graphics package :)

Comment: Amazing...  Really makes one wonder...   So, if I create an image to use that is rounded, I should make the background transparent, and then set to Custom?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
         btReturn.BackgroundView = null;
         btReturn.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
```

Also refer the following links,

[How to change background color of UIButton in Monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733213/how-to-change-background-color-of-uibutton-in-monotouch)

[How to set the background color on a DialogViewController (Monotouch.Dialog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312150/how-to-set-the-background-color-on-a-dialogviewcontroller-monotouch-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808888/is-it-even-possible-to-change-a-uibuttons-background-color) there is an example aswell on how to create your own button, as you cannot modify the rounded button.